# How would I sort some connected values from a csv? Python

Tags: python, sorting, csv

Okay so I'm having some trouble alphabetically sorting values from a csv file.

The format of the file that the program is reading from is: **serialnumber, productname, count, coldorhot**

*The user will input the serial number
and what I want to do is display product name and count in alphabetical order according to product name*

So the output would be in alphabetical order and only showing values that have the same serial number that the user inputted:**productname, count**

thanks for your help

Comment: Can you give an example of input an expected output?

Comment: input: 1129,cup,42,cold

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 1):

I would do it with [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('your_file_name.csv')
data = data.sort('productname') #sort by product name
serialnumber = input('insert serial number:')
result = data[data['serialnumber']==serialnumber] #here you filter by serialnumber 
print "Your products:"
print result
```

without pandas, I would use the csv library:

```
import csv
from operator import itemgetter

serialnumber = input('insert serial number:')
reader = csv.DictReader( open('your_file_name.csv') )

#filter by serial...
result = [row for row in reader if row['serialnumber'] == serialnumber ]
#sort by name...
sorted_result = sorted(result , key=itemgetter('productname')) 
#print the result:
for r in sorted_result:
    print "%s, %s, %s, %s" %(r['serialnumber'], r['productname'], r['count'], r['coldorhot'])
```

Comment: thanks for this, do you know a way to do it without pandas? thanks

Comment: thanks again! Will I be able to incorporate this into a loop as I have multiple lines of csv to sort?

Comment: this is the "loop": result = [row for row in reader if row['serialnumber'] == serialnumber ]